# How can I get the range of a hyperlink in Excel?

Tags: excel, office-js, exceljs

I am trying to get the range for all of the hyperlinks in a given selected range. I do not see a given method to do this like how you can with a formula. I was wondering if this is possible in Office.js

Answer (score 0):

I see there's [Excel.RangeHyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.rangehyperlink?view=excel-js-preview) interface for Range, could be get use `range.hyperlink`, seems only coule get single cell's hyperlink.
Wish this could help you.